# Texts with special characters

Tags: list-manipulation, text

I am finding difficulties to create several lines of text using the following described below:

[image]

I tried to use the functions: `ToStrings`, `TextString`, `ToExpression`, but nothing worked out.

The difficulty arises because the existence of "spaces", "<", ">","/" that need to be used in this texts.

I intend to enter values from a list at each step. Including the zeros must remain. "1" must be "01":

```
values={{01,03,05},{08,09,10},{07,08,15}}
```

This is one of my attempts, but without sucess:

```
ToString["  <valores="#" dataCriacao=\"24/11/2016\" grupo=\"Grupo1\">
   <conc=\"-1\" dataAssociacao=\"01/12/2016\" />
 </LMC>"] & /@ values
```

How should I proceed?

**Update**

The values of the list should be separated by spaces.

This is the result I want to get:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template = "  <valores=\"``\" dataCriacao=\"24/11/2016\" \
grupo=\"Grupo1\">
    <conc=\"-1\" dataAssociacao=\"01/12/2016\" />
  </LMC>";

Apply[StringJoin][
 StringTemplate[
    template, InsertionFunction -> StringRiffle   (*ads " " between*)
 ] /@ IntegerString[values, 10, 2]                (*makes "01" from 1*)
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use `StringJoin`, `ToString` and `Riffle` to get everything in the right place.  First, make the values into strings:

```
values = {
  {01, 03, 05}, {08, 09, 10}, {07, 08, 15}
} /. {
  (*Replace all single digit integers with 0 followed by the number as a string*)
  x_Integer /; x < 10 :> "0" <> ToString[x], 
  (*Replace all double digit integers with the number as a string*)
  x_Integer /; x > 9 :> ToString[x]
};
```

Next, use `Riffle` and `StringJoin` to make each of the sets of three into a single string:

```
strings = StringJoin[Riffle[#, " "]] & /@ values;
```

Finally, put these into your full string:

```
StringJoin[{
  "  <valores= \"", 
  ToString[#], 
  "\"  dataCriacao=\"24/11/2016\" grupo=\"Grupo1\">
   <conc=\"-1\" dataAssociacao=\"01/12/2016\" />
 </LMC>"
}] & /@ strings

(*{"  <valores= \"01 03 05\"  dataCriacao=\"24/11/2016\" grupo=\"Grupo1\
\">
    <conc=\"-1\" dataAssociacao=\"01/12/2016\" />
  </LMC>", "  <valores= \"08 09 10\"  dataCriacao=\"24/11/2016\" \
grupo=\"Grupo1\">
    <conc=\"-1\" dataAssociacao=\"01/12/2016\" />
  </LMC>", "  <valores= \"07 08 15\"  dataCriacao=\"24/11/2016\" \
grupo=\"Grupo1\">
    <conc=\"-1\" dataAssociacao=\"01/12/2016\" />
  </LMC>"}*)
```